# Should you hide modals or remove them from the DOM in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, modal-dialog, electron

I'm writing a React application with a lot of modals (but only one ever active at a time with no nested modals), and I'm unsure of which of these two solutions is preferable when it comes to handling showing and hiding these modals:

1. Have a state boolean variable in the parent component that determines whether or not the modal should be shown. If this boolean variable is false, don't render the component. If it's true, render it. Allow the modal to influence this event via a passed in props callback it can leverage. Example snippets:

   ```
   { this.state.prompt === "makePW" ? 
     <MakePassword closeModal={this.closePWModal} /> : 
     null
   }
   ```

   Now, within the component, it is always visible and does not control its lifecycle. If it is being rendered then it is visible.
2. Just always show the component in the parent component, like so:

   ```
   <MakePassword />
   ```

   Then within the component itself handle its entire lifecycle. That is, the component will have a boolean state variable for its visibility. Some snippets for this approach:

   ```
   <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.closeModal}>
       <Modal.Header>Header</Modal.Header>
       <Modal.Content>Body</Modal.Content>
   </Modal>
   ```

There are also hybrid approaches, and other solutions as well I'm sure.

Regardless, I suppose the essence of my question is wondering about the preferable solution for showing and hiding modals: is it to always render them and just toggle their visibility, or to actually toggle between adding and removing them from the DOM? And, should the modal itself generally control its lifecycle or should the parent?

Comment: Either. I personally don't render modals on components that won't ever use them but have them render hidden on ones that do. This makes for nice transitions and saves overhead where they are not needed.

Comment: If either solution is preferable, what other potential criteria should I use to base the decision on? I don't think I'll use transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i prefer 1st one but if you want to use the second , i would extend the makepassword component from PureComponent to optimize your component.

Instead of writing shouldComponentUpdate() by hand, you can inherit from React.PureComponent. It is equivalent to implementing shouldComponentUpdate() with a shallow comparison of current and previous props and state. - source react docs

```
class MakePassword extends React.PureComponent{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your application.

For example, React-Bootstrap modals stay in the DOM and that allows for nice in/out animations.

Comment: I don't use transitions and I don't _think_ I ever will. If this is the case could it be better to remove it from the DOM?

Comment: If you don't intend to use transitions, then I agree that there isn't much of a reason to keep it in the DOM.

Comment: Any opinions on who should control the show/hide status of the modal? The modal itself or the parent container?

Comment: The parent should control whether or not to render a Modal element, otherwise you'll still end up with a Modal element in the component tree, regardless of it it renders `null` or some JSX.